# Removing first (default) column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to pandas, and I have a dataframe (which I get after processing) that looks like this:
[image: this]
I was unable to find any help/info regarding how can I remove the first column (row_number/ index) to make it like this:
[image: this]

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: additional question example: 
[image: third]

Comment: If you're talking about the index, you cannot remove it, just prevent exporting it (e.g. as csv or xlsx, use `index=False` during export)

Comment: yes, was talking about index.. thanks, for the info

Comment: you can also use reset_index() to reset the index to be your `row` column if you desire.

Comment: by the way, can I also remove the column name?

Comment: All columns must have names. What column are you speaking of?

Comment: see the third image (i updated the question)

Comment: sorry I meant `set_index()`

Comment: if you remove the column names you'll get 0, 1, 2 as column names - a dataframe has columns and columns have column names.

Comment: you can not remove column name like you have in last image. You can however take custom column names if you want.

Comment: no issues, was just casually asking. My main concern was index column

Comment: thanks everyone for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand everything correctly then your dataframe looks like this:

```
   row   fruit  color
0    0   apple    red
1    1   berry   blue
2    2  grapes  green
```

Now if you want to write dataframe to a csv file without first column indexing then use `dataframe.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)` so that the file.csv file will look like this:

```
row,fruit,color
0,apple,red
1,berry,blue
2,grapes,green
```

And to remove header or first row use `header=False` to `dataframe.to_csv("file.csv", index=False, header=False)`. Then your file.csv will look like:

```
0,apple,red
1,berry,blue
2,grapes,green
```

Hope this helps!!! And keep up the work toward learning Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn 'row' into your index, and remove the existing ("autonumbered" so to speak) index: `df.set_index("row", inplace=True)`

You can see all the options for set_index in the pandas docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html